# problem copy original vector into my vector

Tags: c++, vector, copy, std

i have a question:

if i have:

```
void test (std::vector<int> *original)
{
    myvector = vector<int>();
    myvector.reserve(&original.size());
    copy(original.begin(),original.end(),back_inserter(myvector));
}
```

I want to copy a vector in my original target vector

I have 3 error:

Error   1   error C2228: left of '.size' must have class/struct/union
Error   2   error C2228: left of '.begin' must have class/struct/union
Error   3   error C2228: left of '.end' must have class/struct/union

why???

Comment: As an aside, why not use the obvious: `myvector = *original;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `original` is a *pointer*. You have to write it like this:

```
void test (std::vector<int> *original)
{
    myvector = vector<int>();
    myvector.reserve(original->size());
    copy(original->begin(), original->end(), back_inserter(myvector));
}
```

Pointers are dereferenced with `->`, not with `.`. `&` means "take the address of".

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
//if you create a new vector object!
std::vector<int> myvector(original->begin(), original->end());
```

Or,

```
//if you want to populate an already created vector object!
myvector.clear(); //if you want to erase existing elements!
myvector.insert(myvector.end(), original->begin(), original->end());
```

Comment: Why not `insert` in the second case, after the `clear`? `back_inserter` is incredibly useful for situations where you need to provide an output iterator, but (as your first example wisely takes advantage of) this isn't one of those.

Answer (score 1):

Should be `original->size()`, `original->begin()`, `original->end()`. `original` is a raw pointer, you can't use `.` on it, use `->` to get "member of the pointed-to object".

Answer (score 0):

`original` is a pointer - use `original->size()` `original->begin()` `original->end()`

Also, `myvector = vector<int>();` should preferably be replaced with `myvector.clear();`

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some confusion about pointers here. You have passed in a pointer, so should dereference it with -> not .